# How to configure Akka.NET to log all messages received by actors?

Tags: c#, logging, akka.net

I am trying to make Akka.NET log all messages received by actors but can't get this to work. Here's my configuration (I am using projects from Akka.NET bootcamp):

> ```
>       akka {                
>         stdout-loglevel = DEBUG
>         loglevel = DEBUG
>         log-config-on-start = on
>
>         actor {
>           debug {
>             receive = on # log any received message
>             autoreceive= on # log automatically received messages, e.g. PoisonPill
>             lifecycle = on # log actor lifecycle changes
>             event-stream = on # log subscription changes for Akka.NET event stream
>             unhandled = on # log unhandled messages sent to actors
>           }
>         }
>       }
> ```

I can see that the configuration works for other activities (I see debug messages about actor system initialization and shutdown) but nothing from actual messages sent to actors. I tried both C# and F# examples.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found what I was missing. It's not enough to configure debug logging, an actor must implement a marker interface (with no methods) ILogReceive:

```
class ConsoleWriterActor : UntypedActor, ILogReceive
```

Comment: You're correct.  Seems like a "strange" design decision to me.

Comment: @mwardm concur! esp. when I want to see received messages by asking actors

Comment: Any idea how to make it work with F# actors spawned with `spawn` function?